Why does Flask + ReportLab lets me only make 1 pdf before I need to restart server?
I am trying to make a small app for making pdfs and all is good until I try to make a second pdf.
Here are the steps to encounter the issue:

Run flask app
Go to 127.0.0.1:5000
Fill in the form fields then submit
Check generated pdf (it works!)
Back in the browser so that we see the form and fill it out again
Submit
Check generated pdf (it does not work)
Restart the flask server and try above steps again (it works but again only for the first attempt)

This is the flask app I am using. create.html is just a html form and the data grabbed will be sent to pdfCreater.py to generate the
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import pdfcreater 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        keys  = request.form.keys()
        data = []
        temp = []

        for key in keys:
           temp.append(request.form[key])

        for i in range(0, len(temp), 4):
            data.append([temp[i], temp[i+1], temp[i+2], temp[i+3]])
        print()
        return redirect(url_for("createPdf", formData=data))
    else:
        return render_template("create.html")

@app.route("/<formData>")
def createPdf(formData):
    pdfcreater.main(formData)

    return f"<h1>{formData}</h1>"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


Here is pdfCreater.py:
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch, cm
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import Spacer, SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, Paragraph, paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
        

story = [Spacer(1, 0)]

def main(data):
   
    def my_first_page(canvas, doc):
 
        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        title_style = ParagraphStyle(
            name='TitleStyle',
            parent=styles['Title'],  # Inherit from the default Title style
            fontName='Helvetica-Bold',  # Specify the font name
            fontSize=24,  # Set the font size
            leading=28,  # Adjust line spacing
            alignment=1  # Center the title
        )


        centered_style = ParagraphStyle(
            name='CenteredStyle',
            parent=styles['Normal'],  # Inherit from the default Normal style
            alignment=1,  # Align the text to the center
            fontSize=14,
            leading=16
        )


        customer_style = ParagraphStyle(
            name='CenteredStyle',
            parent=styles['Normal'],  # Inherit from the default Normal style
            alignment=1,  # Align the text to the center
            fontSize=16,
            leading=20
        )



        left_align = ParagraphStyle(
            name='reightAlignedStyle',
            parent=styles['Normal'],  # Inherit from the default Normal style
            alignment=0,  # Align the text to the right
            fontSize=14,
            leading=0
        )

        right_align = ParagraphStyle(
            name='reightAlignedStyle',
            parent=styles['Normal'],  # Inherit from the default Normal style
            alignment=2,  # Align the text to the right
            fontSize=14,
            leading=16
        )


        sig_style = ParagraphStyle(
            name='signature',
            parent=styles['Normal'],  # Inherit from the default Normal style
            alignment=0,  # Align the text to the right
            fontSize=11,
            leading=0
        )


        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        blank_line = Paragraph("", title_style)
        title = Paragraph("SOMETHING SOMETHING", title_style)
        story.append(title)
    

        line_of_text = Paragraph(CONFIDENTIAL", centered_style)
        story.append(line_of_text)
        story.append(blank_line)


        date_invoice = "Date: 22/12/00"
        iNum = 12345
        invoice_num = f"Invoice: {iNum}"
        l1 = Paragraph(date_invoice, left_align)
        l2 = Paragraph(invoice_num, right_align)
        story.append(l1)
        story.append(l2)


        customer = "customeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeer"
        l3 = Paragraph(customer, customer_style)
        story.append(l3)


        
        invoice_data = [["gdata", "a", "b", "c"]]
        invoice_data = [
        ['Item', 'Description', 'Description', 'Price'],
        ['Item 2', 'Description 2', 'Description 1', 'Price']
            ]
        print("=================", data[0])
        for item in data:
            invoice_data.append(item)

        while len(invoice_data) < 21:
            invoice_data.append([])
        # ... other items
        

        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        table = Table(invoice_data, colWidths=[1.25 * cm, 12.25 * cm, 2.5 *cm, 3 * cm])


        n = -1
    # Apply table styles (customize as needed)
        table.setStyle(TableStyle([
            ('ALIGN', (1, 1), (-1, -1), 'LEFT'),
            ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'grey'),
            ('SPAN', (0, n), (2, n)),
            ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'MIDDLE'),
            ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, 'black'),
            ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, 'black'),
        ]))


        story.append(table)

        for i in range(6):
            story.append(blank_line)
        sig = Paragraph("_"*24, left_align)
        story.append(sig)
        story.append(blank_line) 
        story.append(blank_line) 
        story.append(blank_line) 
        story.append(Paragraph('Signature of customer/receiving officer', sig_style))
            
        story.append(blank_line) 
        story.append(blank_line) 
        story.append(blank_line) 
        story.append(blank_line) 
        story.append(blank_line) 

        story.append(sig)
        story.append(blank_line)
        story.append(blank_line) 
        story.append(blank_line)
        story.append(Spacer(5 * cm, 0)) 
        story.append(Paragraph('Name of customer/receiving officer', sig_style))
    try:
        print("-----------",type(eval(data)) == type([]))

        if type(eval(data)) == type([]):  
        
            data = eval(data)

            # fetch_data(data)
            doc = SimpleDocTemplate("invoice.pdf", pagesize=letter)
            # Assuming 'taaable' is your table object

            doc.build(story, onFirstPage=my_first_page, onLaterPages=my_first_page)

    except:
        pass

Any idea why this happens?
Thanks in advance!
After searching the internet I tried caching as well as trying to identify bottlenecks in the code but couldn't find anything.

What error does it throw? also the code you shared seems buggy on this line: line_of_text = Paragraph(CONFIDENTIAL", centered_style)
Is CONFIDENTIAL supposed to be a string?

No errors are thrown. The second generated pdf is just blank and seems to be infinitely loading. CONFIDENTIAL is just some dummy text I put instead of the actual text that's supposed to be there, my bad for not closing that string
